# ElasticSearch. How to get counts for several ranges in one query?

Tags: count, group-by, elasticsearch, range

Currently I am getting count for a range of values via this query:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_count' -d '{
    range:{myfield:{gt:"start_val",lt:"end_val"}}
}
'
```

Now I have several ranges, and need counts for each range. Can I get them with one query, rather then re-querying each time?

I looked into [multi-search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-search/) with *search_type=count* But probably it's not the right approach to follow... (it gave me just some aggregated count rather than grouping by... looks like I misused it)

**EDIT:** I've found that [range facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/range-facet/) would have been amazing, but unfortunately my values are neither numbers, nor dates, they're just strings...

**EDIT2:** This is what I ended up with, based on the **accepted** answer:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?search_type=count' -d '{
    facets : {
        range1 : {
            filter : {
                range:{myfield:{gt:"start_val1",lt:"end_val1"}}
            }
        },
        range2 : {
            filter : {
                range:{myfield:{gt:"start_val2",lt:"end_val2"}}
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a link where the creator of ES gives a solution (i.e : several filter facets)

[solution](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Non-Numeric-Range-Facet-td2866042.html)

So, one filter facet per range should work alright.

Here's the link toward the doc :

[doc api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/filter-facet/)

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question with what I ended up with, based on your answer.

Comment: Glad I could be of help